# search for non-free photos and videos in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

How do I get a list of non-free photos and videos in Google Photos? A *free* file is a file that doesn't count against my storage quota (e.g. because it was uploaded in high quality before 2021-06-01 or it was backed up from a Google Pixel phone when the free plan was active).

I want to watch some of them online, download them all, and then delete them from Google Photos. I'm expecting that I have about 5000 non-free and 50000 free photos and videos in total.

Ideally, I'd get a table with the following columns: ID, view-link, delete-link, actual-quota-used.

I'm looking for a photos.google.com website feature, a desktop app for Windows or Linux, a Chrome extension, a set of Google Photos API features, or an Android app.

I'm aware of the following workarounds, and they are not useful for me:

- Getting a list of all original quality photos and videos. (Some of my non-free photos and videos are high quality, others are original quality.)
- Converting all original quality photos and videos to high quality. (I know that Google provides a tool for that. I need to get these photos and videos downloaded and deleted from Google Photos.)
- Getting a list of photos and videos ordered by file size or width or height. (Some of my non-free photos and videos are large, others are small. Also, some of my free photos and videos are large, others are small.)
- Getting a list of photos and videos of which Google thinks are large. (Some of my non-free photos and videos are large, others are some of them are small. Also, some of my free photos and videos are large, others are small.)

Comment: This isn't possible as of now.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Shame on Google, per the norm

Comment: Any updates? I have a Google Pixel 4a with free high quality storage so I'd like this list as well so I can download, delete and upload via Google Pixel 4a Google Photos.